# JAVA: Can I enforce only one thread creation?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Is there a way to enforce only a single execution of a thread object?
 Something like a thread singleton?

To illustrate, consider below example:

1. I have a runnable implemented class.
2. I would like that I will be able to call start() method only one time of the object.

Comment: What do you expect when you call `start()` again? Would it fail or restart the same thread?

Comment: java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() why not to use it ??

Comment: @AhmadWabbi To fall, to ignore the call.

Comment: Instead of implementing Runnable, you can extend Thread. That is by definition only 1-time-startable. If that is no option, you'll have to introduce a flag as suggested in the answers.

Comment: @john I am not against it :) . I will check it. Thanks

Comment: @john After reading about newSingleThreadExecutor, it was said that if the thread terminates, new thread will be created. Given the thread will be terminated when system is closed, should it create any problems?

Comment: @dushkin Are you asking if the thread will keep the program from closing?

Comment: @Fildor, even If we introduce a flag in Runnable class still we can start a new thread by : new Thread(Runnable).start(),

Comment: @Kayaman No. I just wonder if there would be any collision if the program would like to end when, by definition, closing the thread will try to open a new thread. Of course I can simply test it and see..

Comment: @pbajpai21 True, but in that case you can simply exit the run method. Not  perfect but a way to come to the behavior that I think the OP is required.

Comment: @Fildor, I agree with you, we can do it for the sake of doing like this, but If we are strictly want to have solution for the problem statement: ""Can I enforce only one thread creation? "" then I don't think that we have any solution for it, because although we can exit from run() method on basis of that flag, but still we will have a thread for a short time(even its not guaranteed).

Comment: @pbajpai21 That's why I suggested to change implementation into extending Thread rather than implementing Runnable. The Flag-Solution was only a "workaround" if you will. In general, I refrain from extending Thread, though. Perhaps, if we knew what the OP actually tries to achieve, then we could come up with something more sophisticated. I am pretty sure what he is asking here is not really necessary to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a boolean as attribute to check if the thread has already been launch

Comment: Le Blond - Yes, I hoped for a more language structured solution. Thanks

Comment: @dushkin you can only call Thread.start() once as it is, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess that problem is, that OP does not extend Thread but implement Runnable. You could have the same instance (of the class that implements Runnable) be run by two Threads, right ...

Comment: @PeterLawrey Of course I can call it only once. But then I am open for calling it again against the system architucture which requires only one thread to be executed. I am searching for a singleton-alike solution.

Comment: @dushkin I am unclear as to why you are calling it more than once if you don't want to call it more than once.

Comment: @dushkin I would start the thread once on startup/initilisation, and not call start() on it again.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess I wasn't expressing my self well. Of course I won't call it again. But I do have an option to if I would have liked to, and this is what I want to block

Answer (score 0):

Add a `static` `boolean` field in your `Runnable` and check it at the start of the `run` method like this:

```
synchronized(MyRunnable.class) {
    if(alreadyRan) {
        return;
    }
    alreadyRan = true;
}
```

Comment: Sync scope is a bit broad here, isn't it?

Comment: @Fildor An `AtomicBoolean` could be used instead of the `synchronized` and the `boolean` but i don't see a problem here

Comment: I disagree with that **static** flag. That would mean you can run only one instance of the class? I really doubt that is the requirement. As I read it, OP wants that one single instance can only be run once.

Comment: @Fildor ok with that but it depends on the requirement and it's not really explicit from the OP

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the tips of my friends here in this thread, I reached the following:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {

    static private TestThread _instance = null;

    private TestThread() {}

    public static TestThread getThread(){

        if(_instance == null)
            _instance = new TestThread();

        return _instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

And this is an example of using it, when calling start for the second time throws an exception:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            TestThread.getThread().start();
            TestThread.getThread().start();
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Tried to start more than one instance of this thread!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Your comments are welcomed.